# Remove surrounding array from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

does anyone know how I can remove a surrounding array from an array of objects? In my case, I only have one object in this array. `[{"id":"6","email":"test@test.com"}]` Also, would the solution work in the case of multiple objects in the array? Thanks!

Comment: 1. `arr = arr[0]`, 2. no. Explain why you need this, sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: How does this sound like an XY problem? Getting the first value of an array is a common thing

Comment: 1. Thanks 2. Does the need make a difference? Its a yes or no answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of objects.  That's great, because it's the easiest way to store and manipulate lists of records.

You can use array methods like [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that allow you to treat each record separately, telling it what to do individually with each element.  That's also great, because it basically "removes the element from the array" while still processing the whole array, which is what I think you're after.

Simple example to create a dropdown:

```js
const data = [{"id":"6","email":"test@test.com"}, {"id":"12","email":"test2@test.com"}];
const drawEmailDropdown = () => {
  let options = data.map(d => `<option value='${d.id}'>${d.email}</option>`);
  return `<select>` + options.join("") + `</select>`;
};

document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = drawEmailDropdown();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```